# Fragment Content Transition

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions

I'm trying to preform a simple transition. I've added this to the onCreate method of my Fragment. I've looked over the FragmentTransaction documentation but I don't see anything I need to specify when I'm adding it to the activity. I get no effect from the code below. Thanks for any help.

```
    Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    slide.addTarget(R.id.cardview_container);
    slide.setInterpolator(
            AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(getContext(), android.R.interpolator.linear_out_slow_in));
    slide.setDuration(1000);
    setEnterTransition(slide);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the slide transition before adding it to the activity instead of inside the onCreate.

For example

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentYouWantToAdd()

Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
slide.addTarget(R.id.cardview_container);
slide.setInterpolator(
        AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(getContext(), android.R.interpolator.linear_out_slow_in));
slide.setDuration(1000);
fragment.setEnterTransition(slide); // Setting transitions to the fragment

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, fragment)
    .commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also be simply add transition to fragments by using XML. By creating transitions in `anim` folder. For example 
let an transition,

**enter_from_left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="460"/>
</set>
```

Above transition set the enter from left slide transition to your fragment while creating or entering to it. 
Then set it to your fragment as,

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.setEnterTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

And if you want to add exit transition also then simply use `setCustomAnimations()`. As,

```
fragment.setCustomAnimations(enterTransition, exitTransition);
```